# Search does not find metric spaces book recommendations

Tags: bug, search

When [searching for questions containing the words "metric spaces book recommendation"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=metric+spaces+book+recommendation+), I did not find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89642/a-good-book-for-metric-spaces) nor [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471031/book-for-metric-spaces). I only found one of those through [Google](https://www.google.co.za/search?safe=active&client=safari&hl=en-za&ei=WYd2VrXAOsr5UMuCufAD&q=metric+spaces+book+recommendation&oq=metric+spaces+book+recommendation&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...0.0.0.1112772.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..1.0.0.0.eCcGZekAogw&biw=768&bih=928&dpr=2&cad=cbv&sei=s4t2VtbnO4SGU4Tng4gC), which was linked to the other one. Why did the search feature on MSE not work?

Answer (score 5):

The question text of those two questions doesn't contain the word "recommendation".

I suggest you [search for questions with the tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=metric+spaces+[book-recommendation]+is%3Aq) [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation), that turns up some additional questions.

Comment: Combination of tags [metric-spaces+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces+book-recommendation) might be a reasonable choice, too. If is also worth mentioning that [before the tag for book recommendations was created](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books), ([tag:reference-request]) was used for the same purpose. So it is also worth trying to search using this tag.